# Ruby on Rails: errors.add_to_base vs. errors.add

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, model

I have read that errors.add_to_base should be used for errors associated with the object and not a specific attribute.  I am having trouble conceptualizing what this means.  Could someone provide an example of when I would want to use each?

For example, I have a Band model and each Band has a Genre.  When I validate the presence of a genre, if the genre is missing should the error be added to the base?

The more examples the better

Thank you!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

A missing genre would be a field error.  A base error would be something like an exact duplicate of an existing record, where the problem wasn't tied to any specific field but rather to the record as a whole (or at lest to some combination of fields).

Answer (score 121):

It's worth noting (since this shows up in the search engines, which is how I found it) that this is deprecated. The Rails 3 way of doing it is below but is no longer valid as of Rails 7 (see the comment from April 2022)

```
errors[:base] << "Error message"
```

the preferred way of doing it is

```
errors.add(:base, "Error message")
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Errors/add_to_base
http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActiveModel/Errors/add

Comment: One can also specify the attribute in Rails 3. `errors.add(:name, "Error message")` Citation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-add

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer either shoveling into the array or `#add`?

Comment: `.add` allows for options and has a default value for the message if not given. Otherwise they are identical.

Comment: My intuition prefers `errors.add(:base, "Error message')`. For what it's worth, which is not much.

Comment: errors[:base] << "Error message" no longer works in Rails 7. Instead, use the errors.add suggestion.

Answer (score 35):

In this example, you can see field validation (team must be chosen). And you can see a class/base level validation. For example, you required at least one method of contact, a phone or an email:

```
class Registrant
  include MongoMapper::Document

  # Attributes ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
  key :name, String, :required => true
  key :email, String
  key :phone, String

  # Associations :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
  key :team_id, ObjectId
  belongs_to :team
...
  # Validations :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
  validate :validate_team_selection
  validate :validate_contact_method
...

  private

  def validate_contact_method
    # one or the other must be provided
    if phone.empty? and email.empty?
      errors.add_to_base("At least one form of contact must be entered: phone or email" )
    end
  end

  def validate_team_selection
    if registration_setup.require_team_at_signup
      if team_id.nil?
        errors.add(:team, "must be selected" )
      end
    end
  end
end
```